# Jekyll 24 hours build time?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to move a community blog to Jekyll with 26k posts. Every day at least 5/6 new posts we are going to publish. First, I tried with 500 posts so everything was great but now looks like something wrong or Jekyll is not suitable for my requirements. Is there any way to build with it faster? What are best practices in Jekyll for 26k or more web sites?

```
$ jekyll build --profile
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Configuration file: /Users/****/Desktop/Blog/test/jekyll/mysite/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/****/Desktop/Blog/test/jekyll/mysite
       Destination: /Users/****/Desktop/Blog/test/jekyll/mysite/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 

Filename                                                                                            | Count |       Bytes |      Time
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+----------
_includes/sidebar.html                                                                              | 23324 | 2428672.65K | 68515.572
_layouts/default.html                                                                               | 21330 | 2384451.87K | 66784.726
_includes/sidebar-icon-links.html                                                                   | 23324 |   92088.80K | 39129.854
_includes/sidebar-nav-links.html                                                                    | 23324 | 2320100.26K | 29357.133
_layouts/post.html                                                                                  | 17769 |   67024.01K | 18833.855
_includes/post-tags.html                                                                            | 17769 |     869.13K | 18813.715
_includes/page-links.html                                                                           | 23324 | 1156884.07K | 17997.675
_includes/category-links.html                                                                       | 23324 | 1159321.26K | 11325.112
_layouts/day-archive.html                                                                           |  1860 |  199476.16K |  1649.141
_layouts/month-archive.html                                                                         |   122 |   16533.29K |   121.753
_layouts/index.html                                                                                 |  3554 |   69096.50K |    87.228
_includes/head.html                                                                                 | 23324 |   22678.52K |    25.691
_layouts/year-archive.html                                                                          |    12 |    4954.47K |    11.302
_includes/post-meta.html                                                                            | 21323 |    4268.72K |    11.221
_layouts/tags.html                                                                                  |     1 |     193.33K |     4.362
_includes/tags-list.html                                                                            |     1 |     193.33K |     4.359
_includes/copyright.html                                                                            | 23324 |    1480.53K |     3.962
_includes/google-analytics.html                                                                     | 23324 |      22.78K |     3.389
_includes/favicons.html                                                                             | 23324 |    2915.50K |     2.486
_includes/font-includes.html                                                                        | 23324 |    2004.41K |     1.205
_includes/svg/tags.svg                                                                              | 23832 |    6888.94K |     1.128
_includes/custom-nav-links.html                                                                     | 23324 |    1343.86K |     1.047
_includes/svg/github.svg                                                                            | 23324 |   44233.60K |     0.915
_includes/pagination-older.html                                                                     |  3554 |     377.12K |     0.753
_includes/svg/search.svg                                                                            | 23324 |    9065.38K |     0.684
_includes/svg/back-arrow.svg                                                                        | 23323 |    5010.80K |     0.678
archive/index.html                                                                                  |     1 |    2626.28K |     0.666
_includes/svg/download.svg                                                                          | 23324 |    4669.36K |     0.632
_includes/svg/feed.svg                                                                              | 23324 |    8040.40K |     0.629
_includes/custom-head.html                                                                          | 23324 |    3097.72K |     0.627
_includes/custom-icon-links.html                                                                    | 23324 |    1366.64K |     0.595
_includes/custom-foot.html                                                                          | 21330 |     687.39K |     0.577
_includes/pagination-newer.html                                                                     |  3554 |     377.12K |     0.553
feed.xml                                                                                            |     1 |     383.78K |     0.225
_posts/2006-03-26-*****************************************.markdown                                |     1 |       5.02K |     0.054
_layouts/category.html                                                                              |     2 |       1.19K |     0.034
_posts/2005-04-07-*******************************************************.markdown                  |     1 |      28.51K |     0.015
_posts/2006-07-23-**************************.markdown                                               |     1 |       5.68K |     0.012

                    done in 87758.356 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

Comment: This screams 'use Hugo'! https://novelist.xyz/tech/hugo-vs-jekyll-static-site-generator/

Comment: Can you tell if you have any plugins running. I significantly increased my build time because I once misunderstood how to use plugins and wrote a bug. Now I have a blog with 500 pages which is generated in a few seconds (like 5 or 6)

Answer (score 2):

First (and obvious) suggestion: avoid or reduce the O(n) loops in your code at minimum.

Then as from your stats you are reusing `includes` a lot, you can use https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-include-cache which will speed things up a lot, from its docs:

> If you have a computationally expensive include (such as a sidebar or
>   navigation), Jekyll Include Cache renders the include once, and then
>   reuses the output any time that includes is called with the same
>   arguments, potentially speeding up your site's build significantly.